# Spinner Loader Fade out Adjustment Problem

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am creating a spinner loader for the website. So i have an issue in the fade out. There are some images in certain webpages section that will be displayed. And the issue i have is for the main page, i have a set of images need to be loaded fully until the slider will register it and become a slider. I want the slider to fade out at the exact moment it turns into a slider. Now there are also some pages that will have images but not the slider. And i want it to load as quick as possible and disable the spinner. The issue i had is the spinner needs to have vary loading time for the fadeout function. I am using

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $('.spinner-wrapper').fadeOut();
    }, 2000);
```

Now the case now is not my ideal solution. But is there a way to determine when the page is fully loaded and then after loading finish will deactivate the spinner. I want the spinner to based on the webpage loading time and not a predefined time.

The code i am using for the spinner and slider images are below:

This is the Spinner Section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}">

</head>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<body>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->

        <div class="spinner-wrapper">
            <div class="spinner-border text-light" role="status">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
            </div>
         </div>

</body>
```

Next is the Slider and images section:

```
<div class="title_bar title_bar_1">Featured Client</div>
    <div class="container">
     <section class="customer-logos">
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/logo/360-interactive-profile.jpg') }}" alt="360" class=""></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/Honda.jpg') }}" alt="honda"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/genting.png') }}" alt="genting"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/Albee.png') }}" alt="albee"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/poslaju.jpg') }}" alt="poslaju"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/beaconhospital.jpg') }}" alt="beaconhospital"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/CleanPro.png') }}" alt="cleanpro"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/Creation Soft Nepal Pvt. Ltd.jpg') }}" alt="creationsoft"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/Dynasty Dragon.png') }}" alt="dynastydragon"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/J&T.png') }}" alt="j&t"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/MCA.jpg') }}" alt="mca"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/Mookee1.jpg') }}" alt="mookee"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/PKR1.jpg') }}" alt="pkr"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/moonpalace.jpg') }}" alt="moonpalace"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/Mpsegamat.jpg') }}" alt="mpsegamat"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/prabhu1.jpg') }}" alt="prabhu"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/tiseno.jpg') }}" alt="tiseno"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/torum.jpg') }}"alt="Torum"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/umno1.png') }}" alt="umno"></div>
     </section>
  </div>
```

This below is the CSS section of the spinner code styles.css:

```
 /* Styles for the overlay */
 
.spinner-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100dvh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    z-index: 999999; /* Ensure the overlay is on top of other content */
    align-items: center;
  }

  /* Spinner styles */
  .spinner-border {
    width: 60px; /* Adjust width as needed */
    height: 60px; /* Adjust height as needed */
    /* border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: spin 1.2s linear infinite;  */
  }
```

Then below is the JS section of both of this codes:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"y></script> -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/owl.carousel.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/slick.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>
/*slick js to run client logo*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Fade out the spinner overlay after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.spinner-wrapper').fadeOut();
    }, 2000);

    // Initialize the Slick slider
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToScroll: 5,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        lazyLoad: 'progressive', // Enable lazy loading
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }]
    });
    // Listen for the 'lazyLoaded' event of the Slick slider
    // $('.customer-logos').on('lazyLoaded', function(event, slick, image, imageSource) {
    //     // Check if all images are loaded
    //     if (slick.slideCount === slick.$slides.length) {
    //         // Fade out the spinner overlay
    //         $('.spinner-wrapper').fadeOut();
    //     }
    // });
```

});

The lazyloaded is something i tried to use to wait and get the results of the image finished loaded and become slider so that it will cause the spinner to fade but instead it makes the spinner spin nonstop without fading.

[This is the image of the logos images still loading, It is making the images displayed vertically b4 become a slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQaKd.png)

[This is what the slider should look after loading finished. This is supposed when the spinner should fade out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7EDb.jpg)

[And this is another page that needs to use the spinner but it loads for around 5 seconds which felt too long even though it loads faster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDzkF.png)

How should i resolve this?

I try using things like lazyloaded or use something like init but it did not work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  
// Listen for the 'init' event of the Slick slider
$('.customer-logos').on('init', function() {
    // Fade out the spinner overlay
    $('.spinner-wrapper').fadeOut();
});
});
```

It just cause the spinner to keep on loading without fadeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the load event to detect when all the images on the page have finished loading.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
      $('.spinner-wrapper').fadeOut();
});
```

You can use the init event of the Slick slider to fade out the spinner once the slider has been initialized.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.customer-logos').slick({
           });
 $('.customer-logos').on('init', function() {
       $('.spinner-wrapper').fadeOut();
    });
});
```